can't open database file (wrong path to file)
Setup
I am building an webpage (lesson planer). for that I am using dotnet 6 and c#. I am running this on visual studio code.
My Goals

docker container creates the database during the build process.
-create an empty subfolder named 'persistance' in the image, so that my application creates a new database there when starting up, if it doesn't already exist.

Problems
So right now my problem is that when I try to build my project it throws the following error:
16.19 An error occurred using the connection to database 'main' on server '/root/.local/share/persistance/lessons.db'.
16.23 Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'.

that's because of this line in the Dockerfile:
RUN mkdir /app/persistance

and
RUN dotnet ef database update

I understand the problem. In my context file ive created the database like this:
public class LessonContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; }

    public string DbPath { get; }

    public LessonContext()
    {
        var folder = Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData;
        var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(folder);
        DbPath = System.IO.Path.Join(path,"persistance", "lessons.db");
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        => options.UseSqlite($"Data Source={DbPath}");

    
}

So the main problem is how can I save my database in the container in the folder "persitance". My code  doesn't work because the folder is in /app/persitance.
Dockerfile
# Use a lean container to run the application
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-focal AS base

# Create a directory for the app
WORKDIR /app
# Create a directory for persistence
RUN mkdir /app/persistance

# Expose the ports used by the application
EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 5001
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000


# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

# Use a container that contains the complete SDK to build the container
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-focal AS build

WORKDIR /src


# Copy and restore dependencies
COPY ["LessonPlaner.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "LessonPlaner.csproj"

# Copy the rest of the source code
COPY . .


# Build and publish the application
RUN dotnet publish "LessonPlaner.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

# Install Entity Framework Core tools
RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 7.0.5
ENV PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"

# Add EF Core design package
RUN dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design --version 7.0.5

# Create and apply migrations
#RUN dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
RUN dotnet ef database update

WORKDIR /src


# Use the base image for the final stage
FROM base AS final

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the published application to the final image
COPY --from=build /app/publish .

# Enable watchtower
LABEL com.centurylinklabs.watchtower.enable="True"

# Change ownership of the /app directory to appuser
USER root
RUN chown -R appuser /app

# Switch back to appuser
USER appuser

# Set the entry point to run the application
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "LessonPlaner.dll"]

Some informations say you could change  the ASP.NET Core environment to 'Production' with :
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

But I am beginner with Docker so I didn't understand it how this works. So tried some other things.
Ive tried to change the creation of the folder "persitance" in the directory /root/.local/share/. For that I changed this:
RUN mkdir /app/persistance

to
RUN mkdir -p /root/.local/share/persistance

that's throws the same error.
So I thought maybe the folder doesn't get created, for this I debugged with the following command :
RUN ls -la /root/.local/share

right after the creation of the folder, but I didn't get any errors. (RUN ls -la /root/.local/share)

You premusably don't want the database in the container it does not make much senses in most cases. When you need to rebuild the container database will be gone. Rather mount the fitting file/directory when starting the container from some outside filesystem so the database actually persists. If you simply use a docker run command look up the  --mount parameter.

A typical setup is to run the database in a separate container, and avoid mounting any volumes into the application container.  You'd use your application framework's normal database-migration system to create the tables.

it was a goal to have the database in the container. It's not nice but I want to have it in one container. I know that you don't run it in the same box.

I solved my problem by adding the dockerfile like this:

build after database creation

changed name of the initial creat migration, because that one existed

need to changed the path of the "persitance" folder in the lessonContext to this:
public LessonContext()
{
     DbPath = Path.Join("persistance", "lessons.db");
 }



